# Why I get this in Next.js? <link rel=preload> has an invalid `imagesrcset` value

Tags: javascript, css, next.js

I have images in a carousel:

```js
<Image
  src={`http://ticket-t01.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/${props[organizationId].events[programId].imgId}_0.cover.jpg`}
  className={styles.carouselImage}
  layout="responsive"
  width={865}
  height={513}
  key={`${props[organizationId].events[programId].imgId}`}
  priority={true}
/>
```

I think all `src` are set well, as images are visible, rendered. Then what is the problem?

I see this in console:

> has an invalid `imagesrcset` value

Comment: Yeah strange error. `srcSet` is supposed to be optional with `<Image>` in Next. Did you import from `next/image` correctly?

Comment: What `next` version are you on?

Comment: I'm also experiencing this. And if I remove `priority` the error goes away, so maybe it has something to do with that?

And it doesn't seem to have something to do with registering the domain in next.config.js, because in my case I'm loading an image from public folder.

Comment: I still receive the same error. Like @BenBalderas, If I remove ```priority```in nextjs```<Image>``` component, the error is gone. I receive the error in only Safari, not getting the error in Chrome. My image is in the public folder.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

A [bug has been filed with Safari](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=231150) which seems to be the only browser complaining.

I think you can safely ignore this error.

**Update:**
[Bug has been fixed](https://github.com/WebKit/WebKit/pull/16499).

Answer (score 2):

you should add this to your next.config.js file

```
module.exports = {
  images: {
    domains: ["amazonaws.com"],
  },
}
```

from the [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/image-optimization) :

To enable Image Optimization for images hosted on an external website, use an absolute url for the Image src and specify which domains are allowed to be optimized. This is needed to ensure that external urls can't be abused.

Comment: I get this error with local images as well. I don't think that's the issue.

Comment: I agree, I have this setting. Though I get error.

Comment: if the images arrive from `amazon.com` can you explain how that configuration protects from abusing the external urls?

Answer (score 2):

if its a local image
you need to import it, and then use it

```
import dogImg from '../public/dog1.png'

<div>
<Image src={dogImg} />
</div>
```

Comment: This solved the issue for me. FWIW, I only saw this error appear after enabling a Content Security Policy for my site.

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me because I had set `priority = {true}`. Removing `priority` got rid of the error message.

Comment: When i remove the priority tag it says the following:

[DOM] Input elements should have autocomplete attributes (suggested: "current-password"): (More info: https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/create-amazing-password-forms/)

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue because Safari does not support lookbehind regex pattern. I changed it (?=) to (?:) and change `.match` to `.exec` to access the matching groups.

Seems like they update webkit https://github.com/WebKit/WebKit/pull/7109