# Javascript "TypeError: Load Failed" error when calling "fetch" on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, sentry

I'm logging JS client errors using Sentry and there's a lot of "TypeError: Load failed" errors. It's only occurring on iOS. I can't find anything on Google. Is this a native Javascript error or something else? What does it mean? This is separate from a seemingly related issue with "TypeError: cancelled".

[Screenshot from Sentry of the breadcrumbs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqcAK.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: There is no code to add, this is a error appearing in sentry

Comment: Hey @ThomasStewart, were you be able to solve this? I’m facing the same problem! I found nothing on internet

Comment: Hey ! Do you have any updates ?

Comment: "A fetch() promise will reject with a TypeError when a network error is encountered or CORS is misconfigured on the server-side, although this usually means permission issues or similar" from MDN on fetch api

Answer (score 32):

From what I understand, the `fetch` API may deliberately return very limited error details on failure. (Otherwise, a malicious JS program could issue a variety of fetch requests and look at their results to identify which internal servers exist, which servers the user has access to, etc.)

If you have access to a Mac, you can see this for yourself by experimenting with `fetch` requests from the Safari DevTools console. For example:

[image: Screenshot of Safari TevTools console]

The request for `google.com` fails due to CORS. The request for `example.does-not-exist` is an invalid name. The DevTools console gives full details, so a developer who's actually at the browser can troubleshoot, but those details aren't available to JS code; the JS code gets the same "TypeError: Load failed" message in each case.

If you're lucky enough to have a way to access the browser console, you can see more details, but otherwise, I'm not aware of anything you can do to track down the problem - it could presumably be virtually any network error.

Comment: It can be handy to try to reproduce in other browsers too for example. In Chrome for example, I saw the error message that my fetch request was blocked due to the CSP, which wasn't visible in Safari

Answer (score 2):

In my case, this issue appeared mostly on iOS 15 in Safari. By debugging an iPhone through Mac I found that [preload links](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Link_types/preload) with `imagesrcset` are not handled well in Safari (unless de-prioritized), throwing `<link rel=preload> has an invalid imagesrcset value`, as described [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69049527/why-i-get-this-in-next-js-link-rel-preload-has-an-invalid-imagesrcset-value).

The reason why it looks like fetch error in Sentry is that preload link actually [uses fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Link_types/preload) under the hood.

Given it's just the image preload that is failing, and unless it's causing you performance problems, you can safely ignore this particular issue in Sentry until this [webkit Bug 231150 - Safari complains about invalid `imagesrcset` value in  where Chrome doesn't](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=231150) gets fixed.

Comment: The bug has been FIXED 2023-08-10 https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=231150

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem, problems occured because of certificate and iphone took addres api as dangerous.

Helped me get into address api directly in safari or chrome for instance: https://my-adres-api/api/product and then choosing allow to connect with that address.

Now requests works excellent

Answer (score 2):

As of 2023, "Load failed" is the IOS message for when fetch does not respond.  On windows, it's spelled "Failed to fetch".

These messages can be detected in a try/catch(error) around the fetch.  Those strings will be the exact values of error.message