# Fetching API when onClick event is triggered

Tags: javascript, html, async-await

I'm struggling with a (probably fairly simple) HTML & JavaScript issue. And as I'm not much of a frontend guy, I hope there is someone around here who can help me out.

**Task**: A friend with a website, which has been built in Wordpress using the Thrive theme, asked me to write some JavaScript code that calls an API each time a specific button is pressed. Thrive allows to inject custom code in the footer so I created a function to call the API and set it as `onclick` on the `<a>` tag of the button.

Simplied code:

```
async function dummy() {
  var myHeaders = new Headers();
  myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "text/plain");

  var requestOptions = {
    method: "POST",
    headers: myHeaders,
    body: JSON.stringify({}),
    redirect: "follow",
  };

  return fetch("some.api.com", requestOptions);
}

document.getElementById("button1").onclick = async function () {
  var res = await dummy();
  return res.ok;
};
```

**Problem**: While this works without issues in Chrome, Safari and mobile browsers struggle with it. Safari most of the time yields the following exception: `Unhandled Promise Rejection: TypeError: Load failed`.
I played a bit the `await`s and at some point I could make it work on occasion, but never consistently.

Please, could you tell me what I'm overseeing?

PS: I'm aware that this is by no means secure and definitely not production-ready. This is meant to be used solely for demonstration purposes, hence, the quick & dirty way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript "TypeError: Load Failed" error when calling "fetch" on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71280168/javascript-typeerror-load-failed-error-when-calling-fetch-on-ios)

Answer (score 0):

```js
function dummy() {

      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var myHeaders = new Headers();
              myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");

          var requestOptions = {
            method: "GET",
            headers: myHeaders,
            body: JSON.stringify({}),
          };
          
          
          fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(data => {
            resolve(data);
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            reject(error);
          });
      })
}
const main = async()=>{
console.log(await dummy());
console.log("foo bar")
} 

main();
```

Comment: Thanks for your support! I tried both your suggestions but couldn't get it to work either. With your first approach I now get a `TypeError: Load failed` failure (without any further explanation).

Edit: If I run a `fetch` manually from the console, it works without problems